# VB.NET XML Attribute does not appear correctly

Tags: xml, vb.net, attributes

i have to get as output this:

```
<Ricette xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Xml.xsd">
```

but i obtain this:

```
<Ricette xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Xml.xsd">
```

**xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation** doesn't appear correctly

here is a piece of my code:

```
Dim xmlnsXsiAttribute As XmlAttribute = myXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi")
xmlnsXsiAttribute.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
Dim xsiAttribute As XmlAttribute = myXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation")
xsiAttribute.Value = "Xml.xsd"
node.Attributes.Append(xmlnsXsiAttribute)
node.Attributes.Append(xsiAttribute)
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlElement.SetAttribute()` method to add namespaced attribute to an element :

```
....
node.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
node.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "Xml.xsd")
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec5ak8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> ```
> public virtual string SetAttribute(
>   string localName,
>   string namespaceURI,
>   string value
> )
> ```
>
> Sets the value of the attribute with the specified local name and namespace URI.